# aggregate as 'More Than One' all with more than one PER_ID

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions, db2-luw

Result:

- PER_ID,PER_FIRST_NAME,PER_LAST_NAME,RACE
- 814,LeBron,James,Black or African American
- 211,Manu,Ginobili,Argentinian
- 211,Manu,Ginobili,White
- 274,Dirk,Nowitzki,German
- 274,Dirk,Nowitzki,White
- 040,Jeremy Lin,Asian

Desired Result:

- PER_ID,PER_FIRST_NAME,PER_LAST_NAME,RACE
- 814,LeBron,James,Black or African American
- 211,Manu,Ginobili,More Than One
- 274,Dirk,Nowitzki,More Than One
- 040,Jeremy Lin,Asian

Have gone round and round with this.  Need to aggregate `RACE` as `'More Than One'` on all `RACE` with more than one `PER_ID`.

This code displays two columns, distinct `per_id` and count of 2 if `per_id` = 2.

```
    select pr.per_id, count(*)
    from schema1.person_race pr
    group by pr.per_id
```

Have unsuccessfully attempted several other functions to filter including case and sum(case. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this, may be?

```
select 
  PER_ID, PER_FIRST_NAME, PER_LAST_NAME, 
  case CNT when 1 then RACE else 'More Than One' end RACE
from (
  select PER_ID, PER_FIRST_NAME, PER_LAST_NAME, max(RACE) RACE, count(1) CNT 
  from schema1.person_race
  group by PER_ID, PER_FIRST_NAME, PER_LAST_NAME
) t
```

Comment: Looks like some nice code just not able to get it to work.  Here's what I have and it's more specific.  WITH student_basic AS
(
        select pr.per_id
        from schema1.person_race pr
        group by pr.per_id
)

        select 
        SB.PER_ID, 
        p.per_first_name, 
        p.per_last_name
        from schema1.person p
        join student_basic sb on sb.per_id = p.per_id
        inner join schema1.student_enrollment se on sb.per_id = se.per_id
        where se.stu_enr_status = 'E'

;

Comment: Above code is giving me the correct count but as soon as I try to add the 'more than one' race it goes back to counting each individual per_id and I get multiple per_id's in the result set.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you're mixing data values. That is I would create a new column for "Country of Origin" separate from a "Race" column. This would result in one row for Ginobili and Nowitzki in the output.

Comment: This is a situation where a student may self identify as two races and both are listed in a database.  Don't let the race and country of origin confuse the issue.